# How to save the XML From Webservice

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application in which I am getting a  XML file from web service.I am parsing xml from this and showing data in table view. Now I need to save the xml.And i want to show the data when there is no internet connection also. How can I save an XML file coming from web service??? and load it when there is no internet connection.
I can save the xml if the url has name in that,like "www.xyz/asd.xml" but in webservice we dont have xml name like that,so how to save?????
PLEASE HELP ME IN THIS.THANKS IN ADVANCE

```
NSString *link = [[NSString alloc] initWithString://webservice link

    XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] init];
    [parser ParsewithURL:link];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save parsed data using core data or sqlite. If you want to save xml response use NSURLConnection and write the response into a file in documents of iphone.